# Extract everything between pipes in key value pair

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have following sourceString

```
|User=gmailUser1|login with password=false|addition information=|source IP location=DE|
```

I want to extract everything between pipes in key value pair. In this case

1. User=gmailUser1
2. Login with password=false
3. addition information=
4. Source IP location=DE

My regex pattern is giving me the entire string.

```
\|(\b+)=(\b+)\|
```

Comment: You should probably be tokenizing on the pipe, not what's between them. What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Am trying with vbs

Comment: Comments are for asking questions to clarify the question. Details like this should be int he body of the question. You should also use the VBScript tag, assuming it exists.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14103510/1531971

Comment: If an answer helped you, please mark the answer. If not, then maybe add a comment so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the expression:

```
/\|([^=|]+)=([^|]*)/g
```

or if you just want the pattern:

```
\|([^=|]+)=([^|]*)
```

Depending on your environment you will be able to get captures of group 1 and 2 for each key-value pair.

(I'm not able to test it out right now.)

*Update 1:* I did a short test and adapted it with the optimization of Wiktor Stribizew.

*Update 2:* Short explanation of the regex used:

The `\b` in your pattern means *word boundary* and does not represend a sign. You cannot combine it with `+`. See also [What is a word boudary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes).

The first group `([^=|]+)` matches anything that is not a `=` or a `|` with at least one character.

The second group `([^|]*)` matches anything that is not a `=` with zero or more characters (`addition information` has an empty value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`\w+(=|\s|\w+)`

this match:

`\w+` = numletter chars and a matching group

`(=|\s|\w+)` = a `=` sing, blank space or another numletter group